# Dynamic meta titles for pages with URL parameters?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta-tags

I've got a page called /team-page/?id=x that's built in WordPress

The URL parameter of "id" determines the content that will dynamically show on that page. However, my meta title for that page is statically set. Is there a way I can dynamically set the meta title based on the page content? Each variation of /team-page will have a unique H1 - ideally, I'd love to just grab this H1 and set it as the meta title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `document_title_parts` filter. It takes `$titles` as parameter, which consist of two parts - title and site (except for front page - instead of site it's tagline)

So try this

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_title' );
function custom_title( $title ) {

    // Just to see what is $title
    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r( $title );
    // echo '</pre>';
    // die();

    $uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH ); // get current uri without query params

    // Change meta only on team-page. 
    if ( '/team-page/' === $uri ) {
        // you can do here anything you want
        $title['title'] = get_the_title() . ' and whatever string you want ' . $_GET['id'];
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Also don't forget to check and sanitize your `$_GET['id']` if needed.

Comment: This worked beautifully - thanks so much!

Comment: Follow up - not sure if you know the answer to this, but is there any way to make this translate over to sharing this URL on facebook? When I share my /team-page URL on facebook with the ?id=x parameter, it seems to grab the meta title/desc of the canonical URL (eg: /team-page/) and not the URL I'm sharing (/team-page/?id=x).

Comment: Title for facebook (and other socials, twiitter, etc) can be added via `<meta property="og:title" content="Your title for Facebook"/>`. To add it dynamically, use `wp_head` action. There are also a lot of other og-metas (Open graph meta). Link to Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Answer (score 1):

### You're looking for get_query_var()

> Retrieves the value of a query variable in the WP_Query class.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

One small thing to understand is that `get_query_var()` only retrieves public query variables that are recognized by `WP_Query`.

So we need to register our variable first. This is considered best practice. Simply using `$_GET['id']` is **considered to be unsafe** within the Wordpress ecosystem.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpso66660959_query_vars' );
function wpso66660959_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'ref';
    return $qvars;
};
```

Also you should use something other than `id` as it is already used by Wordpress to handle the `WP_Query`. I've used `ref` (reference) but you can choose whatever as long as it doesn't impact Wordpress core.

then we can simply built our custom title.

```
<?= '<title>' . get_the_title() . ' | Order N° ' . get_query_var( 'ref', 'undifined' ) . '</title>'; ?>
```

Note that, if your theme is using Wordpress to set your pages title, you might need to set some sort of conditional statement around [`add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#title-tag), in your `function.php`.

Something like...

```
//...
if ( ! is_page( 'team-page' ) )
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

The `title-tag` is usually included in your theme options.

[image]